# Probability: $a$ chosen randomly from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, find $P(a^2=1 \mod 10)$.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A number $a$ is chosen randomly from the set $\{1, 2,\dots , n\}$. Find
>
> 1. The probability $p_n$ that $a^2=1 \mod 10 $.
> 2. $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} p_n$.

I found that in $n$ numbers $\{1,2,3,\dots, n\}$ there are $(n-1)/10$ numbers that number $10=1$, $(11,21,31,41,51, \dots)$

Hope for any help. Thanks!

Comment: You also have $a\pmod{10}=-1\implies a^2\pmod{10}=1$, so the list should be 1,9,11,19,21,...

Comment: I think we have $$p_n=(\lfloor (n+1)/10\rfloor+\lfloor (n-1)/10\rfloor+1)/n$$ and surely the limit will be $1/5$.

Comment: Hi sting, thank you very much for helping.
I did not understand how you found that 1,9,11,19,21.. (what are the rules?)

Comment: The rule is that $a$ must be congruent to $\pm1$ modulo $10$. Then $\lfloor (n+1)/10\rfloor$ counts the number of $a$'s congruent to $-1$ modulo 10, and $\lfloor (n-1)/10\rfloor+1$ counts the number of $a$'s congruent to $+1$ modulo $10$. That's it.

Comment: right but I nees all a^2(mod)10=1 
so this is less numbers then (n+1)/10+(n-1)/10 , no?

Comment: You do realize that $9^2=81$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $10$, right?

Comment: So $\lfloor (n+1)/10\rfloor$ counts $9,19,29,...$ less than or equal to $n$, whereas $\lfloor (n-1)/10\rfloor+1$ counts $1,11,21,...$ less than or equal to $n$.

Comment: i get it! 
Thank you very much!

Comment: @String I have problem to calculate the limit because the    ⌊ ⌋
how should I do it ? ( for normal Division its 1/5 surely )

Comment: Regarding the limit, you can use the fact that $x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor\leq x$ which gives you $$\tfrac{2n}{10n}-\tfrac1n<p_n\leq\tfrac{2n}{10n}+\tfrac1n$$ and the result should follow, since then $p_n$ is squeezed in between two sequences both tending to $1/5$ being $1/5\pm 1/n$.

Comment: Just to make sure you follow me here, $$\lfloor(n+1)/10\rfloor+\lfloor (n-1)/10\rfloor>(n+1)/10-1+(n-1)/10-1=\tfrac{2n}{10}-2$$ then you add $1$ and divide by $n$ to get the lower bound. The upper bound is simpler, but similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ then we must have that $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ and $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$. As both $5$ and $2$ are primes we must have that $a \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 5$ and $a \equiv 1 \pmod 2$. Combining these two with the Chinese Remainder Theorem we have that:

$$a \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{10}$$

So this proves that the only solutions to $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ are the numbers of the type $a=10k + 1$ and $a=10k-1$. To calculate that number you can use String's formula in the comments.